# Grails, Spring Security & Siteminder - problems with resources or userDetails

Tags: grails, resources, filter, spring-security, siteminder

I am trying to secure my grails application with spring security basing on preAuth by Siteminder. That's basically all I need. The application is used just for checking some stuff so no need for database.

I am stuck on some filter problems that I'm somehow unable to embrace.

At first I used only RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter and custom UserDetails and UserDetailsService.

My spring beans:

```
beans = {
    userDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService)

    userDetailsServiceWrapper(UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper) {
            userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
    }

    preauthAuthProvider(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider) {
            preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService = ref('userDetailsServiceWrapper')
    }

    requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter(RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter){
        principalRequestHeader='SM_USER'
        authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    }
}
```

I have my MyUserDetailsProvider:

```
class MyUserDetailsService  implements GrailsUserDetailsService {

    MyUserDetails  loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{

        //some super secret code here ;)
        return new MyUserDetails(some needed params)
    }
}
```

I also configured secured URLs like in every wise tutorial:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/user/**':['ROLE_MINE'],
    '/activation/**':['ROLE_SOMEOTHER, ROLE_MINE'],
    '/js/**':        ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**':       ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/*':            ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

and some providers (left anonymous as advised in some tutorial):

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['preauthAuthProvider','anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
```

It was working great for data access but it was not allowing to load resources, images in particular. The error said that SM_USER header was not found in request.

So I thought that I can use some solution like 'filters: none' or 'security: none' so that spring would know what url request let without checking for SM_USER.

I tried adding stuff to filter and filterChain:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterNames = ['requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/user/**': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter',
    '/activation/**': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter',
    '/*': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter'
]
```

but it didn't help.

Then I tried using some other filter to be used on the resources without SM_USER header. From reference I understood that Anonymous filter might be enough.

So I made some changes:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['preauthAuthProvider','anonymousAuthenticationProvider']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterNames = ['anonymousAuthenticationFilter','requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter']

grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = ['anonymousAuthenticationFilter','requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter'
```

]

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/user/**': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter',
    '/versionone/**': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter',
    '/activation/**': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter',
    '/js/**': 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
    '/css/**': 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
    '/images/**': 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
    '/*': 'requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter'
]
```

YAY that helped for images. But another problem started to occur.

Instead of myUserDetails object that should be returned when auth is correct I am obtaining some String object quite frequently. And my app is failing on inability to find one property in this String object (which is quite obvious as it's not there ;))

Does anyone know how to deal with that problem? Resigning from showing images is not an option ;)

Is there some way to exclude images/other resources from filterchain in spring security grails configuration...? Just like it was done in normal Java .xml way...?

I will appreciate all the help and suggestions how to solve this.

Thanks !!!

**//EDIT:** if by any chance anyone's using this as a reference to set up security for siteminder sso please note to add :

```
checkForPrincipalChanges = 'true'
invalidateSessionOnPrincipalChange = 'true'
```

properties to your requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter. Otherwise you will be dealing with not updated Authority in http session when calling springSecurityService.getPrincipal() hence users might be 'logged in as someone else'. :) Also consider changing scope of your beans to 'prototype'.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's interested - I found some workarounds for this issue:

**1.** Ask SiteMinder admin to add SM_USER header to all images or to some set of them limited to url location. This is disabled by default due to general performance. Then loose all additional filters and live happily ever after with preAuth one.

**2.** Use static content instead of including images in .war and redirect :]

HOW TO:

Put all needed images in var/www/yourfolder/images
 Add some aliases to your httpd config :

```
Alias /yourapp/imgs var/www/yourfolder/images
ProxyPass /yourapp/imgs !
```

Restart your service
 Be happy using images :D

I am aware that this is not the solution but only workaround. Yet it works.
I will be still happy to hear some better ideas :)

Cheers.