# How to implement NTLM v2 authentication in a Grails application?

Tags: grails, ntlm

I need to implement NTLM v2 authentication in a legacy Grails application. All I've found so far is a Grails *ntlm-auth* plugin, which supports NTLM v1 only and a Java *ntlmv2-auth* library, which I don't know how to attach to the application.

I'll be grateful for any advice on existing plugins or guidelines on integration of *ntlmv2-auth* library into the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache mod_auth_kerb for NTLMv2 authentication. See http://www.grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/ for more details.

Then you must can use either HTTP headers or AJP to pass the autenticated user to Tomcat. See [Forward REMOTE_USER to tomcat via AJP (e.g. for shibboleth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749065/forward-remote-user-to-tomcat-via-ajp-e-g-for-shibboleth) for the AJP solution and https://serverfault.com/questions/207301/get-the-authenticated-user-under-apache for passing the REMOTE_USER in a http header.

In SpringSecurity you can use RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter to get the authenticated user from the header passed from Apache to Tomcat. See [Grails, Spring Security & Siteminder - problems with resources or userDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435242/grails-spring-security-siteminder-problems-with-resources-or-userdetails) for some hints to the correct direction.